# Change MariaDB storage engine to InnoDB for default mysql database tables: db, host and user

Tags: mariadb

One can change the storage engine type for a specific table with:

`ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;`

This works for all tables EXCEPT the db, host and user table that come with the MariaDB/MySQL installation. It throws a (generic) error:

```
MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE db ENGINE = InnoDB;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './mysql/#sql-149_24b' to './mysql/db' (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")
MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE host ENGINE = InnoDB;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './mysql/#sql-149_24b' to './mysql/host' (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")
MariaDB [mysql]> ALTER TABLE user ENGINE = InnoDB;
ERROR 1025 (HY000): Error on rename of './mysql/#sql-149_24b' to './mysql/user' (errno: 168 "Unknown (generic) error from engine")
```

I can see why changing the table engine on a running database would be problematic for these specific tables (as they hold the db and user info). But how would one go about changing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the engone

> In MariaDB 10.3 and before, this table uses the MyISAM storage engine.

Why not update

> In MariaDB 10.4 and later, the mysql.global_priv table has replaced the mysql.user table, and mysql.user should be considered obsolete.

see [manual](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqluser-table/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out I was not aware of this! This solves my predicament.

Answer (score 0):

Do not, repeat do not, attempt to change anything about the definitions of tables in the `mysql`, `information_schema`, or `performance_schema` databases that come predefined in MySQL servers. Those tables are managed by the server software itself and it's possible to corrupt your server if you change them.

Do not attempt to `UPDATE` or `INSERT` rows in those tables, either. Use data definition language SQL statements.

And, `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;` doesn't change the *default* storage engine. Rather, it changes the storage engine of the table called `table_name`.

Comment: Thank you for reiterating this.  I worded my question incorrectly: I indeed just wanted to change the storage engine for those specific tables (the default storage engine for the MariaDB server is already correctly set).